# Sin(1/x) in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to draw the function sin (1/x) in p5. J's and the problem is that I'm  not getting what I expected , i'm getting straight line instead of the oscillation of sin function any help is appreciated

```js
var y;
var x

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  x=-width;
  background(0);
  angleMode(DEGREES)
}

function draw() {
  cord();
  y=sin(1/x)
  if(x>-510&&x<510)
    y=1221550*y
  stroke(0,222,0)
  strokeWeight(4);
  point(x,y);
  if(x<width)
    x+=1;
  stroke(222,2,11)
  strokeWeight(2)
  line(width,height);
}

function Line(w, h) {
  line(-w, 0, w, 0)
  line(0, h, 0, -h)
}

function cord() { 
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  scale(0.5, -0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Remove `if(x>-510&&x<510)`. Furthermore `Line(width,height);` rather than `line(width,height);`

Comment: The graph of y=sin(1/x) only oscillates between roughly x=–0.3 and x=+0.3. If your range of x values extends as far as x=±500, then it's hardly surprising you're not seeing any oscillation. Are you sure you're trying to plot the right equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that the range of the `sin` function is -1.0 to 1.0. To make a sine wave that does not look like a straight line you can multiple by a factor to make it have a bigger amplitude.

Here is an example that is similar to your code that draws a sine wave that you can see.
Keep in mind that the y = 0 is the top of the screen so I add windowHeight/2 to center the wave.

```js
var y;
var x

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  x=0;
  background(0);
  angleMode(DEGREES)
}

function draw() {
  y= (sin(x)* windowHeight/2) + windowHeight/2;

  stroke(0,222,0)
  strokeWeight(4);
  point(x,y);
  if(x<width){
    x+=1;
  } else {
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Now that we can plot the sine of x we can move on to plotting the sine of 1/x. First of all we note that the function is not defined at x = 0. We can get a good plot by just starting at x = 1 to avoid zero. Next we note that the sine of 1/x where x is positive will be approaching zero as 1/x will approach zero as x gets large. Since we know that the sine of zero is zero we expect our plot to approach zero.

Here is a quick sketch that is again based on your code

```js
var y;
var x=1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
  angleMode(DEGREES)
}

function draw() {

  y= (sin(1/x)* 1000 * windowHeight/2) + windowHeight/2;

  stroke(0,222,0)
  strokeWeight(4);
  point(x,y);

  if(x<width){
    x+=.1;
  } else {
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Now we can draw a sketch that plots both negative and positive values. Instead of using x for our angle measurement we can use a variable named theta for the angle. From the above experiments we can see that we are mostly interested in the plot where the angle is close to but not at the value zero. At zero the plot is undefined and anywhere too far away from zero the plot is just something very close to 1.

```js
var y;
var x = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
  angleMode(DEGREES)
}

function draw() {

  // here we use the map function to take our x position and turn it into a value between -1 and 1
  let theta = map(x, 0, width, -1, 1);
 // avoid zero
  if (theta !== 0){
    // calculate a y based on theta and center the plot in the middle of the window
    y= (sin(1/theta) * 1000) + windowHeight/2;
    stroke(0,222,0)
    strokeWeight(4);
    point(x,y);
  }
  if( x < width){
    x+=1;
  } else {
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Now we have everything we need to zoom in very close to 0 and examine the oscillating behavior. Here we will map theta to the numbers between -0.001 an 0.001

```js
var y;
var x = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
  angleMode(DEGREES)
}

function draw() {

  let theta = map(x, 0, width, -.001, .001);
  if (theta !== 0){
    y= (sin(1/theta) * 100) + windowHeight/2;
    stroke(0,222,0)
    strokeWeight(4);
    point(x+10,y);
  }
  if( x < width){
    x+=1;
  } else {
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Take a look at [sin(1/x) and x sin(1/x) Limit Examples](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/sin1overx/) for a deeper look at what is going on with this function.